# show div by clicking Actionlink in mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Div in my view

```
<div style="width:auto; display:none;" id="div11">
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Excel Upload" />
</form>
</div>
```

And one button and one actionlink in another Div

```
<div style="text-align: left; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;">
        <%= Html.ActionLink("Test Link", "", "",null, new {id = "someID" }) %> 
        <button id="Button1">Click</button>
    </div>
```

I want to show the div on click of the actionlink using jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {


                $("#Button1").click(function () {


                    debugger;
                    $("#div11").show();
                });

                $("#someID").click(function () {
                    debugger;
                    $("#div11").css("display", " ");
                    $("#div11").show();
                });

            });
</script>
    Here the button is working fine but don't know why actionlink not working ...Basically i want to show the div by clicking the actionlink.................
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prevent the default link click behavour. You can use `preventDefault` function for that.

The below script will show the div on button click.

```
$(function(){

  $("#SomeID").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#div11").show();
  });

});
```

Assuming your Actionlink syntax is like this.

```
@Html.ActionLink("test link","SomeAction","SomeController",
                                                        null,new {@id="SomeID"})
```

Working jsfiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/kuPau/1/

Comment: like your posts. never used the preventDefault. Will try it.

Comment: @DaveA: Thanks Dave. :) SO is the right place to learn new new things.